# C# What does ? in Arguments Allow

Tags: c#

I have some code: `partial void FuncName(TimeSpan? value)`  What does having the nullable operator there allow me to do?  If it wasn't there could I not pass a null TimeSpan at all?  Do I need it for every argument I pass that could be null?

Thanks

Comment: That means it is `Nullable` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ? is for nullable, it will allow you to pass null in the TimeSpan.

[Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A
>   nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its
>   underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a
>   Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any
>   value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null
>   value.

Answer (score 1):

The sign `?` with DataType indicates that Datatype is nullable.

You can read more about Nullable types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)